# How to apply full join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to apply full join in mysql.

My query:-

```
SELECT * FROM users FULL JOIN userdetails on users.user_id=userdetails.user_id
```

How can i alter my query to achieve full join

Please help

Comment: yes possible through 'LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and UNION'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are lookinf for a full outer join

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN userdetails   on users.user_id=userdetails.user_id
UNION 
SELECT * FROM users 
RIGHT JOIN userdetails   on users.user_id=userdetails.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Left** and **Right outer joins** with **Union** will do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN userdetails ON users.user_id=userdetails.user_id
UNION
SELECT * FROM users RIGHT JOIN userdetails ON users.user_id=userdetails.user_id
```

Comment: You are welcome @youv